# SAML PHP Toolkit with azure as my

Tags: php, azure, saml

I'm using saml php toolkit and aiming to make azure as idp for authentication.! can anybody here . can help me for the idp configuration to submit and receive reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get started from http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/. It shows us a lot of scenarios. Based on your description, you have not described your scenario's details, so it is a bit difficult for us to provide more information at this stage. However since you're using SAML, I’d like to suggest you to look at the first scenario in the document: Web Browser to Web Application. Detailed registration guideline can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn132599.aspx. After Azure registration is complete, it’s needed to follow the steps in http://developers.onelogin.com/v1.0/page/saml-toolkit-for-php to register in OneLogin. Please use the URL like https://login.windows.net/[TenantDomainName]/FederationMetadata/2007-06/FederationMetadata.xml instead of  OneLogin's own identity provider URL. More information can be found at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn195583.aspx. Please feel free to let us know if you need further assistance.

Comment: well appreciated your reply Ming Xu - MSFT  ,,,--  it goes like this i want to create an application for office 365 specifically in outlook then i want this application to have a single sign on capability .... it's like when i login into office 365 account this application weLL also Login there goes i want this app to have a single sign on capability using azure and saml..! hope you can help me further.!!

Comment: Sure, however I’m a bit confused. Do you mean you’re building an Outlook app, e.g. Mail add-in for Office 365 (https://dev.outlook.com/MailAppsGettingStarted/GetStarted)? Please note currently Microsoft only allows us to build such apps using JavaScript, and SSO is handled automatically. Or do you mean you have a custom server based application that will invoke Office 365 API to send/receive emails? You might want to have a look at https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/2138. It shows us how to work with calendar API, but the authentication part is the same for Outlook.

Comment: yes. that's it.! sorry for bad english anyway. but this app where going to build will not dependent to office 365 datas  anymore since its another web  application good example is (salesforce on office 365 outlook application) and  etc..! then since this application that we're planning to create requires user credentials(username and password) in order to  log in .. we need to use single sign on for our app .... and now i currently been focused on how to send and receive request using saml to azure since azure will be our Idp.. ! so.. lead me please  first about this saml :) . thanks much.

Comment: can you show me the steps for this  HTTP Redirect binding to pass an AuthnRequest and HTTP Post binding to post a Response to azure? i already read https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn195589.aspx  but i have no idea on how to do this.!

Comment: or should i say teach me to create a custom sp to send AuthnRequest into azure !???!

Comment: @Looytawon 'but i have no idea on how to do this' - I'd like to suggest you to check if this Walkthrough is what you are looking for
https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php-samples/blob/master/WAAD.WebSSO.PHP/php/docs/Web%20SignOn%20with%20WAAD%20-%20PHP%20sample.docx?raw=true This document provides instructions on setting up a PHP web application and configuring it to leverage Azure Active Directory to accept users from Office365 customers (the “WebSSO” initiative).

Comment: @Looytawon 'or should i say teach me to create a custom sp to send AuthnRequest into azure' - Here is a PHP sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-php-samples/tree/master/WAAD.WebSSO.PHP. Please feel free to follow up if any steps are got stuck during the implementation.